Need Jolt transform with below
Hi I'am trying a jolt transform of below
{
  "Others": {
    "eventTime": "2024-09-05T01:50:05.861",
    "groupArticleNumber": "IW6012",
    "groupModelNumber": "JSO42",
    "seasonCode": "20242"
  },
  "x": [
    {
      "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
      "mainMaterialFlag": true
    }
  ],
  "y": [
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "550"
    },
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "540"
    }
  ]
}

and the expected output as
[
  {
    "eventTime": "2024-09-05T01:50:05.861",
    "groupArticleNumber": "IW6012",
    "groupModelNumber": "JSO42",
    "seasonCode": "20242",
    "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
    "mainMaterialFlag": true,
    "sourcingSizeCode3": "550"
  },
  {
    "eventTime": "2024-09-05T01:50:05.861",
    "groupArticleNumber": "IW6012",
    "groupModelNumber": "JSO42",
    "seasonCode": "20242",
    "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
    "mainMaterialFlag": true,
    "sourcingSizeCode3": "540"
  }
]

I need a jolt spec for same. I have tried so many spec trying multplexing aslo but no luck.

Hi hope this spec helps you resolve your query.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "y": {
        "*": {
          "sourcingSizeCode3": "[#2].sourcingSizeCode3",
          "@(2,Others)": {
            "*": "[#3].&"
          },
          "@(2,x)": {
            "*": {
              "*": "[#4].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]



but some times the X array can have multiple elements like
  "Others": {
    "eventTime": "2024-09-05T01:50:05.861",
    "groupArticleNumber": "IW6012",
    "groupModelNumber": "JSO42",
    "seasonCode": "20242"
  },
  "x": [
    {
      "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
      "mainMaterialFlag": true
    },{
      "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC-123",
      "mainMaterialFlag": false
    }
  ],
  "y": [
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "550"
    },
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "540"
    }
  ]
}```

It's kind of an extension of this former question " #75451057 "  :
Loop through the array of objects with highest numbe of objects, namely "y" while transferring whole content of "Others" object and "x" array inside such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "y": {
        "*": {
          "@2,Others": { "*": "[&1].&" }, // go two levels up the tree to grab the values of the "Others" object
          "@2,x": { "*": { "*": "[&2].&" } },// walk through all deepest elements of "x" array
          "*": "[&1].&" //get all key-value pairs within the objects under the "y" array
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

OR
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "y": {
        "*": {
          "@2,Others|@2,x[0]": {//directly pass content for the zeroth index of the x array
            "*": "[&1].&"
          } , 
          "*": "[&1].&" //get all key-value pairs within the objects under the "y" array
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Edit ( for the new case ) :
You stated whether the input is this one :
{
  "Others": {
    "eventTime": "2024-09-05T01:50:05.861",
    "groupArticleNumber": "IW6012",
    "groupModelNumber": "JSO42",
    "seasonCode": "20242"
  },
  "x": [
    {
      "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
      "mainMaterialFlag": true
    },
    {
      "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC-123",
      "mainMaterialFlag": false
    }
  ],
  "y": [
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "550"
    },
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "540"
    }
  ]
}

then replace @2,x[0] with @2,x[&] , which looks for the dynamic index by the ampersand, within the second provided option such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "y": {
        "*": {
          "@2,Others|@2,x[&]": { //directly pass content for the zeroth index of the x array
            "*": "[&1].&"
          },
          "*": "[&1].&" //get all key-value pairs within the objects under the "y" array
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi @Barbaros Özhan
but some times the X array can have multiple elements like
  "Others": {
    "eventTime": "2024-09-05T01:50:05.861",
    "groupArticleNumber": "IW6012",
    "groupModelNumber": "JSO42",
    "seasonCode": "20242"
  },
  "x": [
    {
      "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
      "mainMaterialFlag": true
    },{
      "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC-123",
      "mainMaterialFlag": false
    }
  ],
  "y": [
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "550"
    },
    {
      "sourcingSizeCode3": "540"
    }
  ]
} ```

I've just replied @jitendrarawat
